# creating custom widget with flask wtforms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am strugling to find resources that explain how to create custom widget with wtforms. I want to display a list of toggle buttons. So far I ve been able to create a list of checkboxes with

```
SelectMultipleFields:
  class PrecisionForm(FlaskForm):
    phone_number = StringField('Phone number', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    contact_emails = SelectMultipleField(
        'Contact emails',
        [at_least_one],
        choices=[],
        option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
        widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
     )
```

but now I want to modify my `widget.CheckBoxInput()` with my custom widget looking like :

`<label class='switch'> <input type='checkbox'><span class='slider round'></span></label>`

I would be very grateful if someone could explain step by step how to do that.

--UPDATE--

I found a way to achieve what I wanted to do but it seems pretty bad :

```
class ToggleButtonWidget(object):
    def __call__(self, field):
        html = '<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" id={} name={} value={}><span class="slider round"></span></label>'.format(field.id, field.name, field.label.__dict__['text'])
        return HTMLString(html)
```

especially this part : `field.label.__dict__['text']` that I use to set the value of my checkbox (the field object from wtforms has no attribute value). Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

The styling of the input field should be done in the frontend. For example, you would have:

```
class CheckBoxWidget(Form):
    box1 = BooleanField()
    box2 = BooleanField()
    ...


widget = FormField(CheckBoxWidget)
```

And then in your html file you would have something like:

```
<div>
    form.widget.label("checkbox-class")
    form.widget("other-checkbox-class")
</div>
```

wrapped inside of your form.

Comment: _Styling_ should be left to the front end, but the OP is wanting to modify the _structure_ to place the `input` inside the `label`.  This is an ugly but common trick when using CSS to define alternate radio and checkbox controls.